# Shiro probelm. a 302 problem occurs when I call an interface that requires permission with logout status

Tags: java, spring-boot, shiro

My code is based on Springboot, and I use shiro to implement login and permission manage.

I have a method to get user info, the data will be returned as json format.

```
@GetMapping("/info")
@RequiresAuthentication
public User info(HttpSession session) {
    return userService.info(session);
}
```

There is my shiro config. **When I logout and call the info method, shiro will redirect the request to loginUrl eg '/user/unauthc'.**

```
@Bean
public ShiroFilterFactoryBean shiroFilterFactoryBean(DefaultWebSecurityManager securityManager) {
    ShiroFilterFactoryBean factoryBean = new ShiroFilterFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setSecurityManager(securityManager);
    factoryBean.setLoginUrl("/user/unauthc");
    factoryBean.setSuccessUrl("/");
    Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    map.put("/user/login", "anon");
    map.put("/**", "authc");
    factoryBean.setFilterChainDefinitionMap(map);
    return factoryBean;
}
```

There is my '/user/unauthc' method. It will be throw an UnauthenticatedException. And I have a handler to catch this exception and return a 403 response.

```
@GetMapping("/unauthc")
public void unauthc() {
    throw new UnauthenticatedException();
}

@ExceptionHandler(UnauthenticatedException.class)
ResponseEntity<String> handleUnauthenticatedException(UnauthenticatedException e) {
    log.info(e.getMessage());
    return new ResponseEntity<>("User not login", HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
}
```

Here is my question: when I test info method with logout status in unit test, I excepted a 403 code. However, I got a 302 code. Even having the same problem in axios request. So how can I solve this problem.

There is my unit test code and the log.

```
@Test
public void testInfo() throws Exception {
    MockHttpSession session = new MockHttpSession();
    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/user/info").session(session))
             .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isUnauthorized());
}
```

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = GET
      Request URI = /user/info
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = []
             Body = null
    Session Attrs = {shiroSavedRequest=org.apache.shiro.web.util.SavedRequest@6af310c7, org.apache.shiro.web.session.HttpServletSession.HOST_SESSION_KEY=localhost}

Handler:
             Type = null

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 302
    Error message = null
          Headers = [Location:"/user/unauthc"]
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = /user/unauthc
          Cookies = []

java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<401> but was:<302>
Expected :401
Actual   :302
```

I try to search this problem but the result I got is to modify `FormAuthenticationFilter`.

Comment: I solve this problem by changing the /user/info from authc to anon. It worked, the unit test and axios will be redirect to /user/unauthc successfully. But I don't know why it worked.